# I can't edit OneDrive Excel document on WP 7.8

Tags: 7.8, onedrive, office-hub

I have a problem with a spreadsheet that is located on OneDrive. It's read-only on my phone.

It started after I updated my phone from 7.5 to 7.8. If I create a new document on my phone, I can edit it without any problems, but when I edit it from OneDrive, it becomes read-only on my phone.

I have searched through the OneDrive options but I couldn't find a solution. Has somebody encountered have this problem before? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem. As soon as Windowa Phone 7.5 upgraded to 7.8 all documents created on my WP7.5 would not open. Same goes for Word and PowerPoint docs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to edit a non-[Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007#Office_Open_XML) document. If this is the case, you'll need to upgrade the document to the Office 2007+ format.

Comment: Ok, is there a setting which set it? How can I change it for my whole skydrive?

Comment: I mean it sounds like the spreadsheet was created with Excel 2003 or earlier. You can only edit Office 2007 or later documents on Windows Phone. Here is a SuperUser question asking how to [convert old documents to the new format](http://superuser.com/questions/32033/batch-convert-doc-to-docx-and-equivilent-for-other-office-formats). If one of these answers works for you, you could do it on your SkyDrive folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, WP and Skydrive doesn't create spreadsheet in Excel 2003 format.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski are you files `.xls` or `.xlsx`?

Comment: It is `.xlsx` format.

Comment: I see. Never mind my answer, I thought they were `.xls`

Comment: In SkyDrive, there is an option to set OpenXML or Office file format.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. But doing below my problem resolved.

Take your spreadsheet and copy everything you want into a new .xlsx but be very careful not to include ANY cells with drop down menus.

My workbook contained Drop down menu, Formula (Function Cell). Also I tried with MACRO enabled file i.e .xlsm. But I was not able to edit those.

You can edit .xlsx here :) ....

Rest if you want to make your excel file more usable with diffrent editing, I will suggest you to quest for those tricks.